# working with object properties - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

How do you reference an object property value from within another property:

```
var myObj = {
              distance: function(){ x=2; y=2; return x + y ;},
              distanceKm:  //here reference to myObj distance's returned value 
            }
```

My object properties hold multiple calculation functions and I wish to access these values from within the same object.

if I use `this` within distanceKM, would I be refering to distanceKM or the parent Object (myObj)
Thanks,

**my usage based on JLRishe's answer :**

```
var myObj = {
    distance: function (unit) {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * this.goingFrom[0] / 180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * this.goingTo[0] / 180;
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * this.goingFrom[1] / 180;
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * this.goingTo[0] / 180;
        var theta = this.goingFrom[0] - this.goingTo[0];
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit == "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344
        };
        if (unit == "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684
        };
        return dist;
    },
    goingFrom: [x1, y1],
    goingTo: [x2, y2]
}
console.log(myObj.distance("N"));
```

Comment: Is `distanceKm` supposed to be a function, or a value?

Comment: Let's suppose both, some are functions that perform a calculation (like distance) others need reference to that value..

Comment: if distanceKm is a function and you invoke that on myObj like `myObj.distanceKm()` then yes `this` in the distanceKm function would refer to myObj.

Comment: myObj.distance is a function definition not a function call. The return value exists only after you actually call it.

Comment: so refering to distance within distanceKm would be calling the function as myObj.distance() instead of this.distance, if distance was a string I would refer as this.distance?

Comment: NB: don't forget you can use a "getter" to make `distanceKm` act like a property, but have its value determined as the return value of a function call!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, an object literal cannot refer to itself, so you cannot do something like this:

```
var myObj = {
    distance: function(){ var x=2, y=2; return x + y ;},
    distanceKm: this.distance() * 1.6 // Will not work -  `this` does not 
                                      // refer to myObj here
};
console.log(myObj.distanceKm);
```

However, if `distanceKm` is a function, then you *can* do this:

```
var myObj = {
    distance: function(){ var x=2, y=2; return x + y ;},
    distanceKm: function() { return this.distance() * 1.6; }
};
console.log(myObj.distanceKm());
```

This is possible because the `this` in the `distanceKm` takes on a meaning when it is actually called (after `myObj` has already been created), not when `myObj` is created.

So it's really a matter of what you are trying to do. As worded, your question is too vague to say anything conclusively one way or the other.

One alternative to the first approach, which will work, is to assign some of the properties after the fact:

```
var myObj = {
    distance: function(){ var x=2, y=2; return x + y ;}
};
myObj.distanceKm = myObj.distance() * 1.6;
console.log(myObj.distanceKm);
```

Another alternative is to use an immediately invoked function, and define some parts before you use your object literal:

```
var myObj = (function () {
    function ds() { var x = 2, y = 2; return x + y; }

    return {
        distance: ds,
        distanceKm: ds() * 1.6
    };
})();
```

As a side note, please use `var` to declare your variables. Using variables without declaring them is very bad practice.

**Edit:** Regarding your specific example, `this` will refer to whatever is before the `.` when you call a function. So you could define your object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    distance: function (unit) {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * this.goingFrom[0] / 180;
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * this.goingTo[0] / 180;
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * this.goingFrom[1] / 180;
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * this.goingTo[0] / 180;
        var theta = this.goingFrom[0] - this.goingTo[0];
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180;
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        if (unit === "K") {
            dist = dist * 1.609344
        } else if (unit === "N") {
            dist = dist * 0.8684
        }
        return dist;
    },
    distanceKm: function () { return this.distance("K"); },
    distanceN: function () { return this.distance("N"); },
    goingFrom: [x1, y1],
    goingTo: [x2, y2]
}
console.log(myObj.distanceKm());
```

Comment: I know the question is to broad but this answer my doubts on when to use this. Thank you

Comment: I have included above my function. Thanks again.